# When to use -ed form of a word instead of -ing when both feel correct

Tags: grammar, tense, verbs

I have a few examples illustrating my problem.

> There, the three figures rested became immobile, lied down on their stomach, deep in a secret game.

VS

> There, the three figures rested became immobile, lying down on their stomach, deep in a secret game.

Another example

> This is the first time I could play badminton.

VS

> The is the first time I am playing badminton.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, *the three figures rested* is not natural in English.

*Rest*, like many verbs, can be transitive (*I rested the book on the table*) or intransitive (*I have a busy night, so I rested this afternoon*). Note that they normally have rather different meanings: an intransitive *rest* corresponding to the transitive, meaning "by supported by something" exists, but is much less common than the other meaning "relax, take ease, stop exerting oneself".

When the past participle (the *-ed* form) is used adjectivally, it usually has a passive meaning, and so only a transitive verb makes sense. So *The three figures rested against the wall* just about makes sense - implying that somebody has leaned these figures against the wall.

Transitive *rest* pretty well always requires another argument, specifying where, or on what, the thing is rested; so *the three figures rested* doesn't make sense. I think you mean *The three figures resting* - intransitive meaning, so only the active *-ing* form makes sense.

Your second example is a completely different issue. The *-ing* form here is not a participle used adjectivally, but part of the "continuous" verb form *am playing*.

It happens that we rarely use this form with a "point of time" expression like "the first time"; so *This is the first time I am playing badminton* is not idiomatic in my English. (I have a suspicion that it is more common in Indian English, but I don't know for sure).

The normal way of expressing this in my (British) English is *This is the first time that I **have played* badminton* - the perfect form because *the first time* implies a period extending up to the present, in which I might have played.

*This is the first time I could play badminton* is grammatical, but has a different meaning, because it implies that previously it was not that I didn't play, but that I couldn't play - maybe I was physically unable, or hadn't learnt, or maybe there was some other restriction that prevented me.

Comment: I don't like that 'lied down on their stomach'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: you're right. I didn't read far enough in the sentence to spot that.